# Unable to boot Ubuntu (minimal bash likeline editing)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, filesystem, 18.10, reinstall

I have a Windows 10- Ubuntu 18.10 dual boot system. I have had some issues with Grub showing me at boot:

```
minimal bash like line editing
```

I tried some troubleshooting and while using gParted with USB live I noticed that Ubuntu filesystem may be corrupted (see screenshot below). Indeed, when trying the normal installing procedures, he shows me that he recognizes existing Windows installation but not Ubuntu's (screenshot below)

I thought to delete Ubuntu partition using Windows Disks Management and then to install Ubuntu again in the same partition. This operation will also reinstall and overwrite the existing grub? I wouldn't want to end up with multiple Ubuntu boot options after this.

[image: my disk partitions]

[image: installation screen]

Comment: It should work without deleting the partition. It should be 'enough' to let the Ubuntu installer select that partition, `/dev/nvme0n1p5` for root, **`/'**, and format it (to replace the previous corrupted file system). That operation should also reinstall and overwrite the existing grub (and there should be **no** extra menu entries).

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is **EoL**, install a LTS version (18.04) or a newer one (19.10 for example)

Comment: I'm afraid of messing up with other disk partitions if I create ubuntu ones manually (i'm a newbie in Linux)...do you think that doing like I wrote above should do the job? I'll go for the 19.10 version